# How to disable double-click zoom in Arcgis Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom

I am using ArcGIS java script API for creating map. I am trying to disable the double-click zoom in the map. Here is link of my map: http://urbanaccessregulations.eu/mindcrew/mobile-popup.html

I used both methods which are given in documentation of Arcgis JS:

```
map.isDoubleClickZoom=false;
map.disableDoubleClickZoom();
```

But still the double click zoom is not disabled - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say your problem is that you're setting the readonly value and so when you go to actually disable it via disableDoubleClickZoom() that code is seeing that it is already disabled and doing nothing.  Remove your first line.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `map.disableDoubleClickZoom();`

*Setting `map.isDoubleClickZoom=false` before calling the above method actually causes the method to fail.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.disableDoubleClickZoom()` and make sure it's declared when the map is loaded. [Others had problems with calling it too early.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/122050/12768)

Answer (score -1):

Use map.disableDoubleClickZoom(true);

this worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Use map.disableDoubleClickZoom(); on map onlaod 
 on(map, "load", function () {
map.disableDoubleClickZoom();
});

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
map.on("load", function (evt) {
    map.disableDoubleClickZoom();               
});
```