# How to disable map navigation in the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4.x

Tags: zoom, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, pan

In the older version 3.x of the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API, it was possible to [disable map navigation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_navigation.html) using `disableMapNavigation()` as explained in [Disabling map in ArcGIS API for Javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122050/disabling-map-in-arcgis-api-for-javascript)

What is the equivalent for disabling map navigation in version 4.x of the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API? The use-case is to prevent map navigation temporarily, while an external query is running.

The mapView has a [navigation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#navigation) property which allows certain types of navigation to be disabled, as in the example at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=view-disable-navigation, but this doesn't seem to allow all navigation to be disabled.

Eg, even when using:

```
navigation: {
  gamepad: {enabled: false},
  browserTouchPanEnabled: false,
  momentumEnabled: false,
  mouseWheelZoomEnabled: false
}
```

the user is able to pan the map with the mouse, zoom by double-clicking, rotate the map using the right-mouse-button, etc.

Comment: This was a very interesting subject to study, it's weird that the option to completely disable navigation was removed with the new API version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to completely disable map navigation (under a condition, like you asked) you would need to stop event propagation from certain events.

```
view.on(["click", "drag", "double-click", "mouse-wheel", "hold", ], function(event) {
  if(thinking){
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

This will stop all of those events, if you want to disable a click or drag event from just the right mouse button (in case you want to disable just rotation for example), then the `click`,`drag` and `double-click` events also have a button property which you can use:

Value   Description
0   left click (or touch)
1   middle click
2   right click

*Taken from the view [event documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-View.html#events-summary)

### EDIT

After asking about Disabling `Shift+Left-click+Drag` zooming as well, I went back to the docs and found this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-disable-zoom/index.html)

Apparently you can add the definition of a pressed keyboard key to the event to stop the event from bubbling.

```
view.on("drag", ["Shift"], function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

view.on("drag", ["Shift", "Control"], function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: edited my answer, added more instructions about ignoring all mouse events

Comment: Yeah, I know, I added that because you wanted to turn the navigation on and off. otherwise you can just create a non interactive map with turning all map events off.

Comment: I just noticed that this doesn't prevent `Shift+Left-click+Drag: Zoom to extent of drawn graphic` (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) Any further suggestions? Thanks https://codepen.io/slead/pen/poEEjwZ

Comment: Adding to the answer

Comment: You are truly the master of finding gold buried in the documentation. Many thanks again

Comment: The really amazing thing is, I don't use the arcgis js api, at all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dror's excellent answer, to prevent the user from using the Zoom In/Out buttons you can create a [Zoom widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Zoom.html) which can then be removed as necessary.

Remove the standard Zoom when instantiating the view using the [ui](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#ui) keyword, and don't include the Zoom control:

```
const view = new MapView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map,
  ui: { components: ["attribution"] }
});
```

Then add/remove a Zoom control as required:

```
let zoomControl = new Zoom({
  view: view
});

// Enable zoom
view.ui.add(zoomControl, {
  position: "top-left"
});

// Disable zoom
view.ui.remove(zoomControl);
```